# useRef takes full control of an outer component instead of the component being used in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a Appbar with material UI. When I use a custom hook. to control the child component it also controls the whole parent component...
My purpose is to use this hook to disappear the component whenever a click is made outside of the component

Here is my custom hook

useListener.js

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export const useListener = (active, ref) => {
  ref = useRef();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState((active = false));

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(event) {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setOpen(!open);
        return;
      }
    }
    // Bind the event listener
    document.body.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // Unbind the event listener on clean up
      document.body.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [open, ref]);
  return [open, ref];
};
```

when I use it in the component by destructing it with

```
const [open, ref] = useListener()
```

and use it inside the component, I set open to appear and disappear the component, with CSS..

```
display: open ? 'block' : 'none'
```

Now when I use this component in which this hook is being used, When I click on this component it appears, and when I click outside of the component (any where else in the body) it disappears, which is totally fine...
But the issue is when I click on the parent component in with this component is being used it also makes appear this child component...
Here is my child component...

Profile.js

```
import React from "react";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import cover from "../assets/cover.webp";
import profilepic from "../assets/profilepic.webp";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { LogoutIcon } from "../assets/LogoutIcon";
import { ChangePasswordIcon } from "../assets/ChangePasswordIcon";
import { useListener } from "../../../hooks/useListener";

const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("authorization");
  localStorage.removeItem("user");
  localStorage.removeItem("permissions");
  window.location.reload(false);
};

const Profile = () => {
  const [open, profileRef] = useListener();
  console.log(profileRef.current);
  return (
    <Box
      ref={profileRef}
      sx={{
        display: open ? "inline" : "none",
        width: "190px",
      }}
    >
      <Paper elevation={2}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <img src={cover} alt="Cover" style={{ width: "190px" }}></img>
          <img
            src={profilepic}
            alt="Profile"
            style={{ height: "62px", width: "62px", borderRadius: "50%" }}
          ></img>
          <Typography variant="button" display="block" gutterBottom>
            Username
          </Typography>
          <Button>
            <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <ChangePasswordIcon sx={{ height: "18px", width: "18px" }} />
              <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                Change password
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={logout}>
            <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <LogoutIcon sx={{ width: "16px", height: "16px" }} />
              <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                Logout
              </Typography>
            </Box>
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

And this is the parent component...

TopbarContents.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import profilepic from "../assets/profilepic.webp";
import Profile from "./Profile";

export const TopbarContents = () => {
  const [profileActive, toggleProfile] = useState(false);

  const openProfile = () => {
    toggleProfile(true);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          width: "100%",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <Typography
            sx={{ color: "#494343" }}
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="div"
          >
            Dashboard
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box
          sx={{
            height: "45px",
            width: "160px",
            borderRadius: 2,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            justifyContent: "center",
            border: "1px solid #e0e0e0",
            pl: "8px",
          }}
        >
          <Typography sx={{ color: "#2E4299", pt: 1 }} variant="caption">
            Case study
          </Typography>

          <Typography sx={{ color: "#494343" }} variant="overline">
            Trial ID: NC48023194
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Button
          color="guava"
          variant="contained"
          size="medium"
          sx={{ fontFamily: "Poppins", mr: 6, ml: 3 }}
        >
          Case Study
        </Button>

        <Button onClick={openProfile}>
          <img
            src={profilepic}
            alt="Profile"
            style={{ height: "62px", width: "62px", borderRadius: "50%" }}
          ></img>
        </Button>
      </Box>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: profileActive ? "inline" : "none",
          flexDirection: "column",
        }}
      >
        <Profile />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: Change `const [open, profileRef] = useListener();` to `const [open, ref] = useListener();`. You can not import profileRef from customHook when you didn't export it.

Comment: @davoodSandoghsaz I didn't understand. Should I just change the profileRef with ref? 
And the hook is fine?